# Change AUTO_INCREMENT value

Tags: mysql

I'm using *MySQL 5.6.12*. I tried this command, but didn't work.

```
ALTER TABLE food AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;  
ALTER TABLE food AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

I tried with my winform application and by *EMS MySQL manager*, neither worked.
I Already tried some of the answers I found here, but nothing yet...

No errors at all. The query executes perfect, it just does not change the AUTO_INCREMENT value.

Comment: We need some more context. Do you get an error? If so, what's the error. What settings holds your food table?

Comment: No errors, the query executes perfect... But when I add antoher row, it still with the old AUTO_INCREMENT value, you know? Nothing change...

Comment: This is a duplicated question. Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17689738/auto-increment-is-not-resetting-in-mysql

Comment: @Wezelkrozum The answer from your *"duplicated question"*, *You cannot reset the counter to a value less than or equal to any that have already been used.*. Yes, you can. I used to do it at work, it's just not working now...

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to lower the auto increment value, it may not work as you expect. From the MySQL [Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-table.html):

> You cannot reset the counter to a value less than or equal to any that have already been used. For MyISAM, if the value is less than or equal to the maximum value currently in the AUTO_INCREMENT column, the value is reset to the current maximum plus one. For InnoDB, if the value is less than the current maximum value in the column, no error occurs and the current sequence value is not changed.

Since you're trying to set it to `1`, this won't work unless the table is empty, since that's necessarily less than the current maximum value.

Comment: I already deleted every single row on my table... It's auto_increment still counting (55 now).

Comment: What engine are you using?

Comment: And the table is empty