# Setting AUTO_INCREMENT attr

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, innodb, auto-increment

What I type in phpMyAdmin

```
ALTER TABLE  `user` AUTO_INCREMENT =1;
```

what I see:

```
SQL-query has been executed successfully
```

in table parameters:

```
AUTO_INCREMENT = 13...
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: That query is fine. Are you sure you're looking at the right place?

Comment: I did not delete entries before query :DDD

Comment: Then that is your answer. If you are resetting auto increment to 1 and 1 already exists it wont work

Comment: I had one record with ID = 12 not 1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17689738/auto-increment-is-not-resetting-in-mysql

Comment: `AUTO_INCREMENT` sets the next value to one more than `MAX(id)`.  Hence 12+1=13.