# how to auto increment with 1 after deleting data from table

Tags: mysql

i'm deleting previous data and trying to insert new list of data,id values are keep on increment because of auto-increment. is it possible to have new auto increment id with 1 ?

and i tried with  `ALTER TABLE table AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;` its not working for me.

Comment: go to phpmyadmin => operation. or `ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
` will work

Comment: i already did it  with mysql ,its not working for me

Comment: which is last id in your table record?

Comment: @saritanelagudda check this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-table.html and more further details i will already share my answer please review it so you can easily find the right solution

Comment: actually i wrote some api that will execute after every 5min and return 20 rows of data i'm storing that in db,after 5min new 20 rows data will come,i'll delete old data and inserting new one that time it is inserting as 21 data..like this it storing now

Comment: so you can use truncate table tableName; while deleting that 20 records. new record will start from one again after truncate

Comment: do u have any idea that how to truncate table using sqlalchemy expressions??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this query while deleting your old 20 Records.

```
truncate table YourTableName;
```

It will reset the database structure and if you insert new record it will start from 1(one) id again.

Comment: Might want to link to the mysql reference https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/truncate-table.html.  I checked it cause I wanted to know more.  Hadn't used this before.  Nice.

Comment: @JimiKimble Always welcome. Thanks for the reference.

Answer (score 0):

> You **cannot reset** the counter to a value less than or equal to the
>   value that is currently in use. For both `InnoDB` and `MyISAM`, if the
>   value is less than or equal to the maximum value currently in the
>   AUTO_INCREMENT column, the value is reset to the current maximum
>   `AUTO_INCREMENT` column value plus one.

And also read this article [Link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-table.html)

Just visit this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17689738/auto-increment-is-not-resetting-in-mysql)